# Reuse Gradle cache in Teamcity CI agents

Tags: gradle, continuous-integration, teamcity, gradle-cache

Given I have multiple agents which build Gradle 5.X based applications, I'd like to start caching Gradle dependencies across all agents.

I tried to share `.gradle` folder, but when I try to run the same build on 2 agents, one of them fails on:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: 

Failed to create parent directory '/home/buildagent/.gradle/caches/5.0' 

when creating directory '/home/buildagent/.gradle/caches/5.0/generated-gradle-jars'
```

How can I share dependencies across Teamcity agents?

Is there a generic solution which will support Gradle 5 onwards?

I found this in [Gradle 6.x documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:cache_copy), but I didn't find anything in `5.x` documentation.

Comment: _share_ as in _mounted network share_ or a cached copy? Is the path (`/home/buildagent/.gradle`) the same on both agents?

Comment: @thokuest
mounted network shares are mounted on VM level to multiple agents

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say what the root cause of the exception you get is, since the message is quite sparse. All I can say is that for Gradle 5 there is no built-in solution to share the local cache via network as you would like to do. The ability to [copy and reuse the cache](https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:cache_copy) you mentioned has been introduced with Gradle 6.1 and has some limitations:

- It is primarily meant to copy contents to other machines, possibly with different directory structures (cache relocation).
- Supports the module cache (`$GRADLE_HOME/caches/modules-<version>`) only
- Network shares most likely only work as [read-only dependency cache](https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:shared-readonly-cache).

So, what's a portable solution that works for Gradle 5 and 6? According to the ticket that originally introduced the cache reusability ([Make dependency caches relocateable #1338](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1338)):

1. Copy, not network mount, the folder. Directory structure must remain consistent across different machines.
2. Mount a previously exported repository with your dependencies:

   > Write a Gradle task that creates a file repository from your dependencies and package that file repository. Then have logic in your build that says "if that file repository is present, use it".
   >
   > (From [this comment](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1338#issuecomment-283667451))